Error bound for MonteCarlo estimate of elements in Gram-Matrix
Suppose I have a $n\times n$-symmetric positive-definite matrix $A$ with elements:
\begin{align}
[A]_{ij}=\int_{\Omega}f_i(x)f_j(x) \, dx, \quad i,j=1,\ldots,n
\end{align}
where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a bounded domain with $\int_\Omega dx=1$ and $f_i:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions.
Suppose now that we sample $N$ points $(x_k)_{k=1}^N$ in $\Omega$ uniformly and create the matrix $A_N$ with elements
$$
[A_N]_{ij}=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N f_i(x_k)f_j(x_k)
$$
Thus, each element in $A_N$ is a Monte-Carlo estimate of the corresponding element in $A$.
Question:
I would like to show that, given a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have that
\begin{align}
|v^T(A^{-1}-A_N^{-1})v|\leq C v^TA^{-1}v, \quad \text{$C$ a constant prefferably independent of $n,N, v$}
\end{align}
with at least probability $p$ which depends on $N$ and possibly $n$.
I want an expression for the probability $p$, and if possible, the expression would be of the form $p=1-\exp(-cN)$.
I would appreciate any thoughts/references relevant to this kind of problem.
Thanks!

What do you mean, precisely, by " high probability" here?

Hi!
Sorry about being to vague. But I would like to show that the given bound holds with at least a probability $p$, where the expression for $p$ depends on $N$ and possibly $n$. A desirable expression would be something like $p\sim 1-exp(-cN)$ so that $p$ goes to $0$ fast with N. I don't know if that's possible to show, but Im interested in that kind of results.

$\newcommand{\Om}{\Omega}\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\newcommand{\De}{\Delta}$The question makes sense only if $A^{-1}$ exists, which will be assumed in what follows. For $x\in\Om$, let $f(x):=[f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)]^\top$, so that $f$ is a random vector in $\R^n$ defined on the probability space $(\Om,P)$, where $P$ is the Lebesgue measure over $\Om$, and $Eff^\top=A=EA_N$. We will assume that the vector function $f$ can be continuously extended to the closure of $\Om$.
Let $g:=A^{-1/2}f$. Then $Egg^\top=I_n$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix, and
\begin{equation*}
    A_N=A^{1/2}B_N A^{1/2},
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    B_N:=\frac1N\,\sum_{k=1}^N X_k \tag{0}\label{0}
\end{equation*}
and $X_k$ is the $n\times n$ random matrix with entries $(X_k)_{ij}=g_i(x_k)g_j(x_k)$ for $i,j=1,\dots,n$.
So, considering $w:=A^{-1/2}v$, rewrite your condition $|v^T(A^{-1}-A_N^{-1})v|\leq C v^TA^{-1}v$ as
\begin{equation*}
    \|B_N^{-1}-I_n\|\le C, \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral matrix norm.
Letting
\begin{equation*}
    \De_N:=B_N-I_n,
\end{equation*}
we have $B_N^{-1}-I_n=-B_N^{-1}\De_N$ and hence $\|B_N^{-1}-I_n\|\le\|B_N^{-1}\|\,\|\De_N\|$. Moreover, if $\|\De_N\|<1$, then
\begin{equation*}
    B_N^{-1}=(I_n+\De_N)^{-1}=I_n-\De_N+\De_N^2-\cdots
\end{equation*}
and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \|B_N^{-1}\|\le1+\|\De_N\|+\|\De_N\|^2+\cdots=\frac1{1-\|\De_N\|}. 
\end{equation*}
So, $\|B_N^{-1}-I_n\|\le\|B_N^{-1}\|\,\|\De_N\|\le\frac{\|\De_N\|}{1-\|\De_N\|}$, and therefore \eqref{10} is implied by
\begin{equation*}
    \|\De_N\|\le\de:=\frac C{1+C}.  \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}
It remains to show that inequality \eqref{20} happens "with high probability". Toward this end, note that $X_1,\dots,X_N$ are i.i.d. random matrices such that $EX_k=I_n$ and $\|X_k-I_n\|\le M$ for some real $M>0$ (because of the assumption that $f$ can be continuously extended to the closure of $\Om$).
So, by Theorem 3.4 with $a=M$, $b=M\sqrt{N}$, $D=1$, and $r=N\de$, we have
\begin{equation}
    P(\|\De_N\|\ge\de)
    =P\Big(\Big\|\frac1N\,\sum_{k=1}^N (X_k-EX_k)\Big\|\ge\de\Big)
    \le2\exp(-N\psi(\de/M)),
\end{equation}
where $\psi(u):=-u+(u+1)\ln(u+1)>0$ for real $u>0$ (and $\psi(u)\sim u^2/2$ as $u\to0$).
Thus, inequality \eqref{20} does happen with "high probability" $\ge1-2\exp(-N\psi(\de/M))$ (which does not directly depend on $n$ or $d$). $\quad\Box$.

thanks for your very good explanation, I really appreciate it :) I understand your derivation, until you state that $|X_k-I_n|\leq M$ follows by the assumption that all $f_i(x)$ can be extended to be continuous on the closure of $\Omega$, how can that be shown?
Also, I guess the constant $M$ will depend on the dimension $n$? Can one say anything about this dependence?
After some thoughts, Im after some expression like $1-exp(- c N/n)$ for the probability. So by making $N$ much larger than $n$ we make the probability close to 1. Thanks!

@Erling : Since the vector function $f$ can be continuously extended to the closure of the bounded domain $\Omega$, we have $|f|:=\sup_{x\in\Omega}|f(x)|\le b$ for some real $b>0$; here, $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$. Since $g=A^{-1/2}f$ and $X_k=g(x_k)g(x_k)^\top$, we have $|X_k|\le|g|^2\le(|A^{-1/2}|,|f|)^2\le|A^{-1/2}|^2,b^2=:M_0<\infty$, where $|A^{-1/2}|$ is the spectral norm of the matrix $A^{-1/2}$. So, $|X_k-I_n|\le M:=M_0+1=|A^{-1/2}|^2,b^2+1$.

Previous comment continued: We see that, naturally, $M$ will be large if $A$ is close to being singular and/or if $|f_i|$'s may take large values.

@Erling : Do you have a further response to my answer and comment?

thanks for your answer. I know that the functions $f_i$ are bounded so thats not a problem. However, Im still wondering the dependency of $n$. Its seems reasonable to get some expression like $N/n$ in the exponent.

@Erling : The bound obtained in my answer does not explicitly depend on $n$; it depends on $n$ only very indirectly, through the bound $b$ on $|f|$ and the measure $|A^{-1/2}|$ of the non-singularity of the matrix $A$. This is natural and desirable. However, if, for some reason, you want to replace $N$ in $1-2\exp(-N\psi(\delta/M))$ by $N/n$, you can certainly do it -- but then you will get a much worse  lower bound $1-2\exp(-(N/n)\psi(\delta/M))$ on the "high probability" (e.g., think what will happen with the latter lower bound when $n\to\infty$).

@Erling : Another way to look at this: You wanted the "high probability" to be close to $1$ for large enough $N$. By dividing $N$ by $n$, you of course diminish the large-$N$ effect.

Yes I understand. Its more that I wonder how to obtain a dependency on $n$ in the constant $M$. When i run some computer experiments I observe that $|\Delta_N|<1$ only if $N>n$, (sufficiently larger) and this is what I want the estimated probability to reflect. Thats why I would like to get something like $N/n$ in the exponent. Now the $n$ dependency is hidden in $M$. So im curious about how to attack the problem om determine this dependency.

@Erling : Your question was "I want an expression for the probability $p$, and if possible, the expression would be of the form $p=1-\exp(-cN)$." Your $c$ was not specified anyhow. My answer gives you such a bound, even with a completely specified and natural $c$. Thus, your question has been completely answered. It was also explained that dividing $N$ by $n$ would only make the bound much worse. If you have further questions about your computer experiments or else, you can post them separately.

Yes I agree that you answered the question. But I dont agree that dividing $N$ by $n$ would be much worse. Now the $n$ dependency is hidden in $M$ and $M$ could scale like $n^s$ for some $s$, which would mean that we would get something like $N/n^{2s}$ in the exponent as $\psi (u)\sim u^{2}$ for small $u$.
